# Where are front end values for Visibility stored in the database?

Tags: magento-1.7, products, products-view

Where are front end values for Visibility stored in the database? Such as Catalog, Search, etc?

Attribute code is stored in, eav_attribute

and the product's value is stored in,

catalog_product_entity_int

But where are the full text names for each visibility option stored?

Not visible individually

Catalog

Search

Catalog, Search

Answer (score 2):

This is a system attribute and its options are generated by source model class. to find out this take a look at the the database table `eav_attribute` and find the attribute with code `visibility` and see the value in column source_model, that is `catalog/product_visibility`, so it means its model file will be available at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Product/Visibility.php`

Open this file and you will get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Frontend labels for attributes are stored in eav_attribute_label table

Comment: That table is empty on my magento installation. Even though they show in admin interface, Not visible individually 
Catalog
Search
Catalog, Search